# Tensorflow deep learning model produces less accuracy for 10 classes, whereas performs very good as set of 3 classes

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am working on a computer vision project, **word classification based on lip movement**.
There are 10 classes (words) to classify. each class in the dataset will have a sequence of images or frames. I chose a time distributed model and LSTM model for the task. Intially, the dataset will be converted into a numpy array which is first fed to the CNN layers to identify features in each images. The result is fed to the Time distributed layer and LSTM to treat the frames as time series. Finally some dense layers are used for classfication.

The problem i am facing is, when i train the model separatly for 3 to 4 classes or words I am getting high accuracy(~ around 80 to 90%) and the prediction is really good. But when I train the model for 10 classes or words all together the accuracy is very very low.

I don't know what is the reason behind this. Could some one help me with this ?

My code

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, Dense, LSTM, Dropout, TimeDistributed,BatchNormalization,MaxPool2D, GlobalMaxPool2D

def convmodel(shape=(24, 48, 3)):
    momentum = .9
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model._name = "CNN1210"
    
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape=shape,padding='same', activation='relu', name = "CNN1") )
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', name = "CNN2"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=momentum , name = "Batch1"))
    
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(name="Maxpool1") )
    
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', name = "CNN3"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', name = "CNN4"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=momentum, name = "batch2") )
    
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(name = "Maxpool2"))
    
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', name = "CNN5"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', name = "CNN6"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=momentum, name = "Batch3") )
    
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(name = "Maxpool3"))
    
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', name = "CNN7"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', name = "CNN8"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=momentum, name = "Batch4"))
    
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(name = "Maxpool4"))
    
    
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', name = "CNN9"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu', name = "CNN10"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=momentum, name = "Batch5"))
    
    
    # flatten...
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name = "Flatten1"))
    
    
    return model



def action_model(shapes , nbout=3):
    # Create our convnet with (112, 112, 3) input shape
    convnet = convmodel(shapes[1:])
    print(convnet)
    print("convolution over")
    # then create our final model
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model._name="1210model"
    # add the convnet with (5, 112, 112, 3) shape
    model.add(TimeDistributed(convnet, input_shape=shapes, name="Timedist1210"))
    print("Time distributed over")
    # here, you can also use GRU or LSTM
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100, name = "LSTM1210"))
    # and finally, we make a decision network
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu', name = "Dense12101"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.8, name = "drop1"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu', name = "Dense12102"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.8, name = "drop2"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', name = "Dense12103"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.7, name = "drop3"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', name = "Dense12104"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.6 ,name = "drop4"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', name = "Dense12105"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.5 ,name = "drop5"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name = "Dense12106"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', name = "Dense12107"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', name = "Dense12108"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu', name = "Dense12109"))
    print("Final dense layer")
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(nbout, activation='softmax', name = "Dense12110"))
        
    return model

TimeDistmodel = action_model((10, 24, 48, 3),10)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001)

TimeDistmodel.compile(
    optimizer,
    'categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['acc']
)

checkpoint_path = "training_all/cp.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

# Create a callback that saves the model's weights
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1)

#TimeDistmodel.summary()
finalModel = TimeDistmodel.fit(trainX,trainY,epochs=100, validation_data=(testX,testY),batch_size= 50, callbacks=[cp_callback])
```

**Output for 10 classes**

```
Epoch 1/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3026 - acc: 0.1033
Epoch 00001: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 259s 3s/step - loss: 2.3026 - acc: 0.1033 - val_loss: 2.3039 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 2/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3029 - acc: 0.1048
Epoch 00002: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 245s 3s/step - loss: 2.3029 - acc: 0.1048 - val_loss: 2.3040 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 3/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3028 - acc: 0.1038
Epoch 00003: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3028 - acc: 0.1038 - val_loss: 2.3040 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 4/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3025 - acc: 0.1041
Epoch 00004: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3025 - acc: 0.1041 - val_loss: 2.3043 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 5/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3025 - acc: 0.0969
Epoch 00005: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3025 - acc: 0.0969 - val_loss: 2.3041 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 6/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00006: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3043 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 7/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1033
Epoch 00007: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1033 - val_loss: 2.3044 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 8/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00008: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3044 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 9/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00009: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3045 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 10/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00010: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 245s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3046 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 11/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00011: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 245s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3046 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 12/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0985
Epoch 00012: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 243s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0985 - val_loss: 2.3046 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 13/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.0954
Epoch 00013: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.0954 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 14/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1015
Epoch 00014: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1015 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 15/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00015: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 245s 3s/step - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 16/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.0997
Epoch 00016: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.0997 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 17/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00017: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 18/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.0974
Epoch 00018: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.0974 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 19/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1000
Epoch 00019: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1000 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 20/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1023
Epoch 00020: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1023 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0929
Epoch 21/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1028
Epoch 00021: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1028 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 22/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00022: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 23/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3025 - acc: 0.0990
Epoch 00023: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3025 - acc: 0.0990 - val_loss: 2.3048 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 24/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00024: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3048 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 25/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1005
Epoch 00025: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1005 - val_loss: 2.3048 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 26/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3025 - acc: 0.0969
Epoch 00026: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3025 - acc: 0.0969 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 27/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1003
Epoch 00027: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 245s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1003 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 28/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00028: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 29/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00029: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3046 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 30/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00030: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 245s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 31/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00031: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 32/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0982
Epoch 00032: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0982 - val_loss: 2.3046 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 33/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00033: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 34/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00034: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 35/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1000
Epoch 00035: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1000 - val_loss: 2.3048 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 36/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0992
Epoch 00036: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0992 - val_loss: 2.3048 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 37/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0977
Epoch 00037: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0977 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 38/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1005
Epoch 00038: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 246s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1005 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 39/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00039: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3046 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 40/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0941
Epoch 00040: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0941 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 41/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0980
Epoch 00041: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0980 - val_loss: 2.3048 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 42/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00042: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 43/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0946
Epoch 00043: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0946 - val_loss: 2.3048 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 44/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00044: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 245s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 45/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0967
Epoch 00045: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0967 - val_loss: 2.3048 - val_acc: 0.0929
Epoch 46/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0967
Epoch 00046: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 245s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0967 - val_loss: 2.3048 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 47/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00047: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 243s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 48/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1010
Epoch 00048: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1010 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0929
Epoch 49/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.0995
Epoch 00049: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.0995 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 50/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00050: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 245s 3s/step - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 51/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00051: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 245s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3046 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 52/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1010
Epoch 00052: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1010 - val_loss: 2.3046 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 53/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00053: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 54/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.0954
Epoch 00054: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.0954 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0929
Epoch 55/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0992
Epoch 00055: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0992 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0935
Epoch 56/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1026
Epoch 00056: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1026 - val_loss: 2.3046 - val_acc: 0.0929
Epoch 57/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1031
Epoch 00057: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1031 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 58/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.0987
Epoch 00058: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.0987 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 59/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0972
Epoch 00059: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0972 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0929
Epoch 60/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1031
Epoch 00060: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1031 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 61/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00061: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 245s 3s/step - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 62/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0957
Epoch 00062: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 245s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0957 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 63/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00063: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 64/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00064: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 245s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 65/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00065: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 66/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00066: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 67/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00067: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 68/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00068: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3048 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 69/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1013
Epoch 00069: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1013 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 70/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1003
Epoch 00070: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1003 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 71/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0972
Epoch 00071: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0972 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 72/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0987
Epoch 00072: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 245s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0987 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 73/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00073: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3048 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 74/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00074: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 75/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00075: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3048 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 76/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1005
Epoch 00076: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1005 - val_loss: 2.3048 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 77/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.0964
Epoch 00077: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 245s 3s/step - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.0964 - val_loss: 2.3048 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 78/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00078: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3048 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 79/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00079: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3048 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 80/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00080: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 245s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3048 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 81/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00081: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3049 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 82/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1013
Epoch 00082: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 245s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1013 - val_loss: 2.3046 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 83/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00083: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3048 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 84/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00084: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3046 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 85/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00085: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 86/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00086: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 245s 3s/step - loss: 2.3023 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 87/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00087: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3046 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 88/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0962
Epoch 00088: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.0962 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
Epoch 89/200
79/79 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036
Epoch 00089: saving model to training_1210\cp.ckpt
79/79 [==============================] - 244s 3s/step - loss: 2.3024 - acc: 0.1036 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.0917
```

Comment: Surely this is just because there is a much higher chance of guessing the correct class when there are less classes. If there were 3 classes then the chance is 33.3% whereas the chance would be 10% if there were 10 classes. So your model will immediately have a better success rate when there are less classes.

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way to make it work for all the classes ?

Comment: Sure, experimentation and determination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because your training data-set of 79 is too small. You can:

1. increase training data-set by acquiring additional data such as this one - http://spandh.dcs.shef.ac.uk/gridcorpus/

Or

2. use pre-trained weights for transfer-learning from some other relevant neural network such as LipNet - https://github.com/rizkiarm/LipNet . Their repository contains step-by-step instructions.